# Using drag and drop in phonegap installed

Tags: ios, cordova, drag-and-drop, phonegap-plugins

I'm using simple HTML code to work on a drag and drop function as part of my IOS app. This piece of code works perfectly in the browser however when I copy it into my xcode file the image won't drag.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #div1 {width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
        </style>
    <script>
        function allowDrop(ev)
        {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

    function drag(ev)
    {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev)
    {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Drag the image into the rectangle:</p>

    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <br>
    <img id="drag1" src="images/face.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This code is what worked in the end.

<script>


var nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName('contents');

for(var i=0;i<nodeList.length;i++) {
    var obj = nodeList[i];
    obj.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
                         var touch = event.targetTouches[0];

                         // Place element where the finger is
                         event.target.style.left = touch.pageX + 'px';
                         event.target.style.top = touch.pageY + 'px';
                         event.preventDefault();

         });


}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading over Apple's webview capabilities document states that you have to set a CSS property for this to work.

From the docs:

```
Making an Element Draggable

WebKit provides automatic support to let users drag common items, such as images, links
and selected text. You can extend this support to include specific elements on an HTML
page. For example, you could mark a particular div or span tag as draggable.

To mark an arbitrary element as draggable, add the -webkit-user-drag attribute
(previously -khtml-user-drag) to the style definition of the element. Because it is a
cascading style sheet (CSS) attribute, you can include it as part of a style definition
or as an inline style attribute on the element tag. The values for this attribute are
listed in Table 1.
```

So standard draggables will work out of the box, but other elements like `div` or `span` require the `-webkit-user-drag` attribute to be appended.

Example:

```
#drag1 { -webkit-user-drag: element; }
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/DragAndDrop.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your input and I thought you were correct however it still doesn't drag in the x-code simulator.

Comment: I'm starting to believe my code is correct but there's a fault in an ios setting or something. Should something be enabled to allow for drag and drop?